# Force fsck on read only root partition

Tags: fsck

For some reason the root partition on my VPS has been remounted in read only mode. I want to force a fsck at reboot and reboot my machine but cannot do this as I cannot create the `forcefsck` file with `touch /forcefsck`.

Is there another way to accomplish this? I cannot boot into another distro as it is a VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the bootloader (via VNC console) or able to edit kernel command-line options in some other way, add options `forcefsck` or `fsck.mode=force`.

Alternatively: Because the filesystem is read-only, you can probably run fsck on it directly. That's how fsck-on-boot is implemented in distributions lacking an initramfs: the rootfs is mounted read-only, checked, and remounted read-write on success (or the system rebooted after repairs).

If the filesystem has detected problems and triggered the remount itself (as opposed to it being triggered by the underlying device), chances are fsck will run on next reboot anyway.